# can valueUnbound() method of HttpSessionBindingListener be used to get informed whenever a session is about to be destroyed?

Tags: java, servlets, listeners

The **valueUnbound()** method of **HttpSessionBindingListener** is used to inform the attribute's object which was added as an attribute in an Http session, that it has been removed from the session. In "**HeadFirst JSP and Servlets**", they say that it can also be indirectly used to notify the application whenever a session is about to be destroyed, along with **HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed**. How is that possible ?

Comment: Hm.. without any experience on that, I would say because the HttpSessionBindingListener is calling the valueUnbound() method when a session is about to be destroyed. Maybe I don't understand the question :)

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding "How is that possible?" part of your question. This is pretty ambiguous in this context. What part exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a dummy object that implements `HttpSessionBindingListener` to the session and never remove it. Then invocation of its `valueUnbound()` would indicate that session is about to be destroyed, and you can do some actions there.

The advantage of this approach is that you can add multiple such objects with different callbacks instead of keeping track of different callbacks in `HttpSessionListener` manually.